# I'm using moment.js diff to compare two times, but the result is incorrect

Tags: momentjs

I'm using moment.js `diff` to compare two times，but the result is incorrect

```js
var moment = require('moment.js')
console.show()
var mydate = new Date();

myhours = mydate.getHours()
myminutes = mydate.getMinutes()

var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, parseInt(myhours), parseInt(myminutes)]);

log(b.diff(a,'minutes'))
```

I want the result to be correct

Comment: Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please format your code and explain what you think is worn and what result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the hours and minutes of myDate like month and day in the array to pass at moment constructor.

You can change `b` with this code:

```js
const b = moment([2007, 0, 29, parseInt(myhours), parseInt(myminutes)]);
```

or using the methods of moment:

```js
const b = moment().year(2007).startOf('minute');
```

`.year()` set the year of date, and `.startOf()` rounds the time to start of minute.

This can be a solution, if I understood what do you want:

```js
const moment = require('moment.js');

const a = moment([2007, 0, 29]); // 2007-01-29 00:00:00
const b = moment().year(2007).startOf('minute'); // 2007-01-12 14:34:00

console.log(b.diff(a, 'minutes')); // -23606 -> use Math.abs(b.diff(a, 'minutes')) for the absolute value, your choice.
```